# Showing a window is never activated

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to show a window from a non UI thread:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher =
Application.Current != null
    ? Application.Current.Dispatcher
    : Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
        window.Topmost = true;

        if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that the window is indeed on top but not activated. 
It is necessary to click on the window that it gets the logical focus.

How can I archive that the window is activated after ShowDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be activated. Try to handle the `Activated` event. Or handle the `Loaded` event and focus a control in the dalog window.

This works, i.e. the `TextBox` is focused without any click:

```
Task.Run(()=> 
{
    Dispatcher dispatcher = Application.Current != null ?
        Application.Current.Dispatcher : Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    if (!dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            Window window = new Window() { Content = tb };
            window.Activated += (ss, ee) => { /* ... */ };
            window.Loaded += (ss, ee) => tb.Focus();
            window.Topmost = true;

            if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
            }
        });
    }
});
```